# How can we get result of summary report parameters (throughput, received & sent bytes) in JMeter script through non gui mode?

Tags: jenkins, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jmeter-3.2

How can we get result of summary report parameters (throughput, received & sent bytes) in JMeter script through non gui mode? I have to implement the benchmarking on whole script rather than each thread to mark the status of script pass/fail by comparing the result to the static .csv file which contains the value of parameters .Kindly let me know the approach to opt.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is going for [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), it can generate various tables and charts out of JMeter's .jtl results file.

So you will need to add the following command as the Post Build Step:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD  --generate-csv SummaryReport.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You can install JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)